# Taking multiple strings and integers in a single line

Tags: c

I want to take multiple integer and strings in a single line such as "45 A4 Paper 217" but I want to store string A4 Paper in a single char array. I tried using scanf but it scans until space for string.

```
int int1;
int int2;
char str1[81];
scanf("%d %s %d",&int1,&str1,&int2);
```

I want str1 to be A4 Paper in str1 array

Comment: Please, post here your attempt, and it would be easier to help you pointing out your mistakes.

Comment: read more on `scanf` , also does this pattern `45 A4 Paper 217` will be the only input? I mean `"number"  "paper size" "paper" "number" ` ?

Comment: IFormat will be "integer multiple string integer" in a single line it will take it in one input

Comment: add error-checking, validation, **indentation**, ... `char *input = "45 A4 Paper 217"; /*or fgets, ...*/ char *firstspace = strchr(input, ' '); char *lastspace = strrchr(input, ' '); int1 = strtol(input, 0, 10); sprintf(str1, "%.*s", (int)(lastspace-firstspace)-1, firstspace + 1); int2 = strtol(lastspace, 0, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` family functions are known as a *poor man's parser*. They can easily parse blank separated tokens, but anything more complex is at best tricky, or even impossible - more exactly other tools should be used.

Your requirement is to accept in a single string any token until an integer token is found (token here being a blank delimited string). This is just not possible in single `scanf`.

If the type and number of blank characters does not matter, you could use a `scanf` loop first trying to find an integer, next getting tokens as string:

```
i = scanf("%d", &int1);      // get first integer
if (i != 1) {
     // error condition
}
char *cur = str1;
for(;;) {
    if (1 == scanf("%d", &int2)) break;    // ok we have found the second integer
    i = scanf("%s", cur);
    if (i != 1) {
         // error condition
    }
    cur += strlen(cur);                   // move cur to end of string
    *cur++ = ' ';                         // and add a space
}
if (cur != str1) {
    cur[-1] = '\0';                       // erase last space
}
```

This should detect read errors, but does not even try to control overflow of `str1`. It should be added for production grade code.

Answer (score 0):

**This is my solution**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
int int1,int2;
char str[100],str1[81];
char *p;
scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
p = strtok (str," ");
sscanf(p, "%d", &int1);
p = strtok (NULL, " ");
strcpy(str1,p);
strcat(str1," ");
p = strtok (NULL, " ");
strcat(str1,p);
p = strtok (NULL, " ");
sscanf(p, "%d", &int2);
printf("%d %s %d",int1,str1,int2);
return 0;
}
```